# Close dialog that contains static text

Tags: applescript

I am trying to write a script that should press OK button on every dialog that contains particular static text:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set theProcesses to application processes
    repeat with theProcess from 1 to count theProcesses
        tell process theProcess
            repeat with x from 1 to count windows
                set texts to static text of window x
                    repeat with t from 1 to (count texts)
                        if (static text t of window x whose value is "Particular text") then
                            click first button whose value is "OK" of window x
                        end if
                    end repeat
                end repeat
            end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

This script is not executing. Something is wrong with the if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check

```
if (value of static text t of window x is "Particular text")
```

---

The `try` block is necessary to ignore the error if an OK button does not exist.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set theProcesses to application processes
    repeat with theProcess from 1 to count theProcesses
        tell process theProcess
            repeat with x from 1 to count windows
                set texts to static text of window x
                repeat with t from 1 to (count texts)
                    if (value of static text t of window x is "Particular text") then
                        try
                            click (first button of window x whose value is "OK")
                        end try
                    end if
                end repeat
            end repeat
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative method of doing this—and one that may, in theory, be quicker if you had a large number of processes, windows and text objects to loop through—would be to grab everything all at once.  This could be done in one, single line, but breaking it down into separate lines doesn't sacrifice anything in terms of speed and affords a much easier-to-read code block:

```
    tell application "System Events"
        set P to a reference to every process
        set W to a reference to every window of P
        set S to a reference to (static texts of W whose value is "Particular text")
        set C to a reference to value of attribute "AXParent" of S
        set B to a reference to (buttons of C whose name is "OK")

        repeat with _b in B
            click _b
        end repeat
    end tell
```

Breaking it down with some crude explanations:

**`P`:** contains a reference to every process.  Because it's a *reference* to every process, rather than simply the processes themselves, AppleScript doesn't need to expend any energy determining what these processes are just yet.  It basically stores the instruction to do this later on within the variable `P`.

**`W`:** is a reference to every window of every process.  So far, these two lines are the equivalent of your first two `repeat` loops, except no computations have been exercised here so far, whereas your script will have gone through (`count windows` × `count processes` computations).

**`S`:** is a reference to all the static texts matching your required value.  For all intents and purposes, this "bypasses" the need to loop through them individually, and just grabs the right ones immediately (in reality, a loop *is* still performed, but it's performed at a deeper code level, which takes a fraction of the time than any loop performed by AppleScript).

**`C`:** contains the parent of the static text, which is the window containing said text. (`C` stands for *container* = *parent*)

**`B`:** is then, ultimately, the collection of all the "OK" buttons of every window that contains the specific static text.  It's a reference to them, so, again, can just grab them all in one go, avoiding the `repeat` loops.

Finally, to click the buttons in `B`, we do our first real bit of computation, and loop through `B`.  However, `B` only contains the buttons that need to be clicked, so there are no wasted iterations, and hence no need for a `try...end try` block.

As each button from `B` is accessed through variable `_b`, this is where AppleScript throws all of those references together, and performs the necessary (and only the necessary) computations needed to retrieve the buttons, which can equate to as few as one single iteration of each of your `repeat` loops.

Though this is already a very efficient means of acquiring the buttons you need to click, we can filter the processes and windows to improve it further:

```
    tell application "System Events"
        set P to a reference to (processes whose background only is false)
        set W to a reference to (windows of P whose subrole is not "AXUnknown" and role is "AXWindow")
        set S to a reference to (static texts of W whose value is "Particular text")
        set C to a reference to value of attribute "AXParent" of S
        set B to a reference to (buttons of C whose name is "OK")

        repeat with _b in B
            click _b
        end repeat
    end tell
```

As I mentioned, the additional advantage is that this requires much less—if any at all—error handling (systems running OS X versions earlier than MacOS 10.12 may need to wrap the `repeat` loop here in a `try` block; in MacOS 10.12 and later, this is not needed).  The `try` block was needed in your script in the event that `first button of window x whose value is "OK"` returned an empty result, which would cause `click` to throw an error.  Here, `B` only contains the buttons named "OK" (change `name` to `value` if needs be), so `click` will always have something to click.

However, for the sake of robustness and to cater for earlier systems, it's probably good practice to be thoughtful when it comes to error-handling:

```
    try
        repeat with _b in B
            click _b
        end repeat
    end try
```

So it might be worth mentioning that your script may need additional error-handling than just the single `try` block: once the button "OK" is clicked, my guess is that the dialog box disappears.  When this happens, the all the static text objects it contains disappear along with it, which means that another error will be thrown by the incomplete `repeat with t` loop.

---

*Thanks to [@user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894) for testing the code in OS X 10.8.6.*

Comment: BTW I just tested your code using a real world scenario in macOS 10.12.6 with an app I created that has a dialog box with the target static text and an OK button and it worked extremely fast compared to the accepted answer which ran 5 times longer and didn't click the OK button when yours did. Although the same app which was actually created under OS X 10.8.6 none of the answers worked to click the actual OK button in the testing under OS X 10.8.6. (even with the try statement) So there is more at issue in the older OS. +1 anyway! :) I'll test tomorrow all other versions after 10.8.6 and see.

Comment: I did some further testing, no error handling necessary from OS X 10.9 and up. Works lighting fast compared to the accepted answer which enumerates  everything, which takes much more time the using a reference to, and never actually clicked the button when yours did.  I'm definitely going to re-code some of  AppleScript  apps thanks to your answer! :)